# Marklogic Audit Log

Tags: marklogic

I would see the below sample audit logging which MarkLogic provides

```
Sample logging : 2012-03-26 10:55:53.735 event=amp-usage; 
function=http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin:read-config-file;
uri=/MarkLogic/admin.xqy; database=filesystem;
success=true; user=admin; roles=admin;
```

Can I customize this message by adding few more details highlighted below like this

Sample logging : 2012-03-26 10:55:53.735 event=amp-usage; 
function=http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin:read-config-file;
uri=/MarkLogic/admin.xqy; database=filesystem;success=true; user=admin;  roles=admin; 
**Received  request for Tenant Id=xxxxx called by source id=xxxx Web. Request ID xxxx**

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of audit logging is to be generated by MarkLogic, and not depend on the application, nor being influenced by it in any way. It should be an independent source to verify/audit the database activity.

I think Trace Event logging is what you are looking for. There are built-in Trace Events, like URL Rewrite:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/appserver-control#id_25611

And you can use [fn:trace](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:trace) to generate custom trace events. Make sure to activate trace events on the Diagnostics page of the appropriate group in the Admin interface, and to add on that same page all relevant trace events to the list of events that should get logged.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this can be achieved.

1. Create a module (say activity-log.xqy) which creates and insert log document [xdmp:document-insert()] into audit database.
2. Call it from another module (say, logger.xqy) which spawns the logging task [xdmp:spawn()], here you will specify the database name, so give audit in that.