# Marklogic Rest Api Logging

Tags: marklogic

I want to log information into Error Log. I have come across `xdmp:log()` as an xQuery function and `MyDocumentManager.startLogging(logger)` in java api. How do I perform the same via Rest Api ??

I can always write an extension for `xdmp:log()` and perform the same via REST API but since java api is built on rest-api so I think definitely they will be a way out.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more how you would want to use the logging? Are you thinking about using MarkLogic as a kind of logging service for your middle-tier?

Comment: @grtjn Lets say before calling any rest service operation, I want to log few application related things at marklogic server

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use MarkLogic as a logging service. You could do that by PUT-ing log entries into a Log database (using /v1/documents on a REST instance pointing to such a database), but you can make it write to ErrorLog.txt as well.

MarkLogic REST-api doesn't provide functionality for this out of the box, other than the built-in Audit logging in MarkLogic. But that is something you cannot influence, so likely not what you are looking for.

I think you are on the right track with a REST extension. That fits naturally into the REST-api, and allows you to use the Java library to call it. It will be a separate REST call though, and you will have to implement the extension yourself.

You can use `xdmp:log`, but you could also consider using `fn:trace`, as suggested in one of your other questions: [Marklogic Audit Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249453/marklogic-audit-log)

HTH!